# Class type as a parameter in Java

Tags: java, oop, object, methods, types

I have a method:

```
private List<ApplicationForVacancy> createListOfApplicationsForVacancy(List<Document> documents) {
        return documents.stream()
                .filter(d -> d instanceof ApplicationForVacancy)
                .map(d -> (ApplicationForVacancy) d)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

but I'd like to pass the name of the class/the type of the class in parameter and return type of the method like this:

```
private List<TypeOfSomeClass> createList (List<Document> documents, String or Type typeOfSomeClass) {
            return documents.stream()
                    .filter(d -> d instanceof typeOfSomeClass)
                    .map(d -> (typeOfSomeClass) d)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Is it possible? How can I do that?

Comment: Not always, but often having to use `instanceof` as you are using it indicates bad design.  Why does your program have the need to sort a list based on the types in that list?

Comment: I know that. That's forced class design for interview test. I can't change it. List<documents> contains a few types and I need to separate it for a few separate lists and I wanted to do it in one method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to provide a `Class` object to declare the type and add a type parameter to the method, like this:

```
private static <T> List<T> filterType(List<?> input, Class<T> clazz) {
    return input.stream()
            .filter(clazz::isInstance)
            .map(clazz::cast)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

You then call the method like this:

```
List<Object> stuff = List.of("String", Integer.valueOf(3), Double.valueOf(42), new Object());
List<String> strings = filterType(stuff, String.class);
List<Number> numbers  = filterType(stuff, Number.class);
```

`strings` will only contain `String` and `numbers` will contain the 2 numeric values.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you very much mate!

Comment: You don’t need to call `valueOf` manually. `List.of("String", 3, 42.0, new Object());` will do.

Comment: @Holger: I'm well aware of that, but I wanted to make the mixed types more explicit.

Comment: Even then, `List.of("String", (Integer)3, (Double)42.0, new Object());` would be enough.

Comment: @Holger: sure, I just happen to prefer this notation.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge you can't perform a type conversion like this. But you could create a new List instance at the start of your method, containing the specified type. Then loop through your existing list, filtering out all instances that should be contained in the result. Add those, then return the new List. Here some pseudo code.

```
public <T> List<T> filterInstances(List<?> input, Class<T> type){
  List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
  for(Object o : input){
    if(type.isAssignableFrom(o.getClass()){
      result.add((T)o);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Solution posted by Joachim Sauer works. Your code is correct too ;) Thanks mate!

Comment: Yes his solution fits your usecase better. I didn't look into the Stream API. I just tried to explain the general procedure :)